# Android Studio 2.0 build gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've just updated Android Studio to version 2.0 built on 5'th April 2016 from a stable channel and now I have a strange error when I try to build my project:

> Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (org.apache.commons.collections.BeanMap$1) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced
>   by a compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The
>   recommended solution is to recompile the class from source, using an
>   up-to-date compiler and without specifying any "-target" type options.
>   The consequence of ignoring this warning is that reflective operations
>   on this class will incorrectly indicate that it is *not* an inner
>   class.

[image: ErrorLog]

Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7.2'
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.1.1'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile files('libs/java-json.jar')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
compile('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.7') {
    exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
}
compile ('com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids', module: 'library'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}

compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.7'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
}
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Are you experiencing lag while compiling ? My i7 with 32 GB RAM and SSD lags so hard I cannot move the mouse while it compiles for 4-5 minutes. I did not have this issue on Android Studio 1.5 with the exact same project.

Comment: "Are you experiencing lag while compiling ?" - YES!!! It freezes my system almost totally for some period until it has finished

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need add to dependencies in build.gradle:
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'